# Angular 4 ngrx/effects testing

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store-4.0

I'm having problem with figuring out the way effects should be tested in Angular 4 application that are using ngrx/store etc.. For Angular2 there was EffectsRunner and EffectsTestingModule but they are not present in ngrx/store version for angular 4. I'm looking for a way to test the effects as well as whole app with store

Answer (score 0):

To test you effects with store you can provide a mock store to your TestBed:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            provideMockActions(() => actions$),
            {provide: Store, useValue: mockStore}
            ...
        ]
    });
```

`mockStore` extends BehaviorSubject and should contain a `dispatch` and `select` method.

You should take a look at the [migration guide](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/MIGRATION.md) for how to test effects in ngrx v4.